# Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'navigationBarBackButtonHidden'

Tags: swiftui

swift ui で

.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

を置こうとすると

Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'navigationBarBackButtonHidden'

というアラートが出ます。

.navigationBarBackButtonHiddenはサポートされてないのでしょうか？

Comment: 何に対してnavigationBarBackButtonHiddenを付与させていますか？

Comment: NavigationViewです。

Comment: 小さいコードで動くはずなので、付与する部分が間違えているかもしれないです。```var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Text("hello")
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
  }```

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで解決しましたが、解決済みにできるようこっちにも載せておきます。

小さいコードで動くはずなので、付与する部分が間違えているかもしれないです。

```swift
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    Text("hello")
  }
  .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。